# video gets out of the parent border in chrome android browser

Tags: css, html, html5-video

my code is

```
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

html

```
<div>
 <video controls>
    <source src="example.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

the code works fine on windows chrome, firefox, edge, and in samsung brwoser, android firefox but not android chrome here is an image :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwiqen8ya7xw9ye/2016-10-22%2008.28.11.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you add your parent html and css?

Comment: Maybe because of browser version.

Comment: answer updated @ZeevKatz

Comment: its the latest version

Comment: You try to add 100% width to your parent?

Comment: didnt work @ZeevKatz

Answer (score 0):

Add

Meta properties

```
name="viewport" content="width=320px, initial-scale=1"
```

---

Then

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with media queries

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
     /*your rules for chrome*/
     div{ 
         //Codes
        }
    video{
         //codes
         }

}
```